# Firefox for Android: can't modify anything on about:config

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, config, firefox-developer-tools

TLDR: firefox for android does not show expected about:config screen.

Firefox: 39.0
Phone: Nexus 5

I am trying to install and configure an extension on firefox for Android. 
I've been following [these instructions](https://champtown.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/using-silent-block-on-android/), which work fine until I have to alter the filepath in about:config.

At this stage, I need to modify the settings to show firefox where a certain .txt file is. I can easily find the setting I wish to modify, but cannot find a way modify it.

The expected menu (with Modify) never shows up, and instead the only options I can get are "copy name" and "copy value".

Images of the expected interface, and actual interface:

Expected interface (from walk-through):

[image]

Actual interface (screenshot):

[image]

After searching, trying to find the modify option:

[image]

Comment: Are you connected to your device with WebIDE? Are you developing an addon or just installing one?

Comment: just installing one. Connected with the device through cable to get the file there, but the problem happens while working directly on the device.

Comment: What i do to install addons that are not upload to the firefox marketplace, I upload to github then use "github extension installer" (i have to switch github to 'request desktop version' though) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/ try this method its much easier then transfering with cable connection

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem here isn't installing the extension (that bit worked fine) but setting up the config so that firefox knows where to look for my list of banned urls. Would your suggestion help with this?

Comment: Oh ok so you have to change a preference? I just loaded about:config and i seem to be able to set things fine. Maybe go to menu of firefox > settings > developer tools > and check "remote debugging". not sure if that fixes it, i didnt need to do it but worth a trial and error

Comment: Got it! (eventually). The interface did change, but it was actually a combination of two mistakes on my side that was keeping me from getting the right answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, with a lot of trial and error, got it fixed. The about:config interface has changed since the guide I was following was pasted, but it ended up being a very good step by step anyway.

**Solution:**
The new interface has an area where there is nothing written, which you need to over-write with the desired path (in my case it ended up being /storage/sdcard0/silent_block_directory).

Two pieces of advice to avoid making the same mistakes as I did:
1. Don't point the path at the .txt file, but rather at the parent directory
2. Don't look for the modify button, it does not exist any more.